# Check multiple servers for a directory existence and copy it

Tags: batch-file

Currently, I have the following batch script which copies the file `MyFile1.accdb` to `C:\Computer`:

```
xcopy "\\serverA\Folder1\FolderInside\MyFile1.accdb" "C:\Computer\" /Y
```

I would like to add various servers to this script, and have it copy only if the directory exists, *(ignore the others)*.

How can I add the following and create an `if` `then` statement?

```
xcopy "\\serverB\Folder1\FolderInside\MyFile1.accdb" "C:\Computer\" /Y

xcopy "\\serverC\Folder1\FolderInside\MyFile1.accdb" "C:\Computer\" /Y

xcopy "\\serverD\Folder1\FolderInside\MyFile1.accdb" "C:\Computer\" /Y
```

e.g.

```
If serverB exists copy ...
If serverC exists copy ...
```

Comment: `if exist "\\serverA\" (copy ….)`

Comment: It ignores anything that doesn't exist. So your sample code works as is.

Comment: I see two answers that are opposite to one another, can someone confirm which is accurate ?

Comment: I can see only one: mine (and Noodles mentioned yours). Test mine and see if it is working.

Comment: So just to confirm your saying to just add if exist before every xcopy line?

Comment: The `IF EXIST` command will not work with server name only.  It requires a share name as well.  Regardless of that it really doesn't matter.  If the server and folder do not exist the `XCOPY` command will immediately fail.  So there really is no point in testing if it exists first.

Comment: It will fail but continue on with the script correct? No messages?

Comment: @JerryJenson why ask a question that you could easily figure out by testing that theory.